# You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE id = '1''

Tags: sql, node.js, database, npm

```
Error: ER_PARSE_ERROR: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE id = '1'' at line 1
    at Query.Sequence._packetToError (D:\Softwares\usermana\Nodejs-UserManagement-Express-Hbs-MySQL\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\sequences\Sequence.js:47:14)  
    at Query.ErrorPacket (D:\Softwares\usermana\Nodejs-UserManagement-Express-Hbs-MySQL\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\sequences\Query.js:79:18)
    at Protocol._parsePacket (D:\Softwares\usermana\Nodejs-UserManagement-Express-Hbs-MySQL\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\Protocol.js:291:23)
    at Parser._parsePacket (D:\Softwares\usermana\Nodejs-UserManagement-Express-Hbs-MySQL\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\Parser.js:433:10)
    at Parser.write (D:\Softwares\usermana\Nodejs-UserManagement-Express-Hbs-MySQL\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\Parser.js:43:10)
    at Protocol.write (D:\Softwares\usermana\Nodejs-UserManagement-Express-Hbs-MySQL\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\Protocol.js:38:16)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (D:\Softwares\usermana\Nodejs-UserManagement-Express-Hbs-MySQL\node_modules\mysql\lib\Connection.js:88:28)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (D:\Softwares\usermana\Nodejs-UserManagement-Express-Hbs-MySQL\node_modules\mysql\lib\Connection.js:526:10)
    at Socket.emit (node:events:390:28)
    at addChunk (node:internal/streams/readable:315:12)
    --------------------
    at Protocol._enqueue (D:\Softwares\usermana\Nodejs-UserManagement-Express-Hbs-MySQL\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\Protocol.js:144:48)
    at Connection.query (D:\Softwares\usermana\Nodejs-UserManagement-Express-Hbs-MySQL\node_modules\mysql\lib\Connection.js:198:25)
    at exports.update (D:\Softwares\usermana\Nodejs-UserManagement-Express-Hbs-MySQL\server\controllers\userController.js:81:14)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (D:\Softwares\usermana\Nodejs-UserManagement-Express-Hbs-MySQL\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
    at next (D:\Softwares\usermana\Nodejs-UserManagement-Express-Hbs-MySQL\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:144:13)
    at Route.dispatch (D:\Softwares\usermana\Nodejs-UserManagement-Express-Hbs-MySQL\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:114:3)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (D:\Softwares\usermana\Nodejs-UserManagement-Express-Hbs-MySQL\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
    at D:\Softwares\usermana\Nodejs-UserManagement-Express-Hbs-MySQL\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:284:15
    at param (D:\Softwares\usermana\Nodejs-UserManagement-Express-Hbs-MySQL\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:365:14)
    at param (D:\Softwares\usermana\Nodejs-UserManagement-Express-Hbs-MySQL\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:376:14) {
  code: 'ER_PARSE_ERROR',
  errno: 1064,
  sqlMessage: "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE id = '1'' at line 1",
  sqlState: '42000',
  index: 0,
 
}
The data from user table:
 undefined
```

Im trying to update my login detatils dynamically from the admin page but it throws an error when I click on submit

Heres my database structure

```
[
```

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: Yikes, plain text passwords and SQL injection in the same post... two of the worst security issues out there. These issues are so bad, you shouldn't even put up with them in practice/proof of concept code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have comma before "where" that mustn't be there. Just remove it.

Answer (score 0):

In your code there is an extra single quotation mark please remove that.

[image]

after the question mark `?'`

**What is the code right now?**

WHERE id = ?' ,

**What should be the code?**

WHERE id = ? ,